# Cannot change the colour of a List Form Web Part

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I am using SharePoint Designer to load a list form web part and want to modify some colors in newform.aspx.

I right-click on this object, go to Properties -> Formatting but can't change anything. What would be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ListFormWebPart is a web part that auto-generates the form, and can't be customized.

You'll need to style it using CSS. You can give it a class using the CssClass property (in code)

`<WebPartPages:ListFormWebPart CssClass="my-style"`

...then target the form elements using using CSS rules

`.form-style table.ms-formtable td.ms-formbody { background: color }`